# Laravel - user status

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm working on small Laravel project (5.8 version) and I need my user to have a status table. I created my status table `$table->smallInteger('status')->default(0);` and all I need now is if I change status to 1 my user should have a button for Post, but if I change it to 0 back again it needs to disappear. 
Here is my `home.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    You are logged in!
                    </br></br>
                        @if($user->autoplac == 1)
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">New post +</a>
                        @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

It shows me `Undefined variable: user`. How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always check the current logged in user with `Auth::user()`, so you could put your button inside an if statement

```
@if(Auth::user()->status)
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! I think it's all working properly now!